# the relation between cohomology and homomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I meet a problem, how can I understand $H^1(M,\mathbb{R})\cong Hom(\pi_1(M),\mathbb{R})$? Where $M$ is a compact manifold. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $H^1$ singular or deRham cohomology?

Comment: @John: Does it matter? Aren't they isomorphic?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: Yes. But there are different path to the isomorphism (if that's the singular one, treating $H_1$ as abelianization of $\pi_1$ and then use universal coefficient theorem might be the better explanation)

Comment: @John: Fair enough. Treating $H_1$ as the abelianisation of $\pi_1$ (together with the de Rham Theorem) is exactly how Lee indicates (in Problem 18-2) one can prove the surjectivity of the map $[\alpha] \mapsto I_{[\alpha]}$ I mention below. I am not too familiar with the Universal Coefficient Theorem; I'd love to see how it plays a role if you have the time to provide an answer.

Comment: @John: Considering the tag "differential-geometry" and the fact that $M$ is assumed to be a manifold, I would assume it's de Rham cohomology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that this isomorphism does not require $M$ to be a compact manifold, only that it is connected.

The isomorphism is given by integrating one-forms along closed curves. That is, if $[\alpha] \in H^1_{\text{dR}}(M)$ define $I_{[\alpha]} \in \operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(M), \mathbb{R})$ by

$$I_{[\alpha]}([\gamma]) = \int_{\gamma}\alpha.$$

First, one needs to check that this map is well-defined (independent of the choices of representatives of $[\alpha]$ and $[\gamma]$). This is done in Theorem 17.7 of Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (second edition), where it is also proved that the assignment $[\alpha] \mapsto I_{[\alpha]}$ is injective. The surjectivity of this map is the goal of Problem 18-2 of the same book.

**Added Later:** In the comments, the OP wanted to know whether $H^n_{\text{dR}}(M) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(\pi_n(M), \mathbb{R})$ for any other values of $n$. The answer is no.

First of all, for $n = 0$, $\pi_0(M)$ is not a group so $\operatorname{Hom}(\pi_0(M), \mathbb{R})$ is not defined.

For $n > 1$, consider $M = (S^1)^n$, the $n$-dimensional torus. We have

$$\pi_n(M) = \pi_n((S^1)^n) = (\pi_n(S^1))^n = 0,$$

so $\operatorname{Hom}(\pi_n(M), \mathbb{R}) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(0, \mathbb{R}) \cong 0$, but $H^n_{\text{dR}}(M) = \mathbb{R}$ as $M$ is a connected, compact, orientable $n$-dimensional manifold.

Comment: Is it right for $n$? That is to say, $H^n(M,\mathbb{R})\cong Hom(\pi_n(M),\mathbb{R})$, $\alpha\mapsto (\Sigma\mapsto \int_\Sigma \alpha)$?

Comment: No. We have $\pi_3(S^2) = \mathbb{Z}$ (which is generated by the Hopf fibration), so $\operatorname{Hom}(\pi_3(S^2), \mathbb{R}) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}$, but $H^3_{\text{dR}}(S^2) = 0$.

Comment: So it is just right for $n=1$?

Comment: Simpler still, for the torus $T$, $\pi_2(T) = \pi_2(S^1\times S^1) \cong \pi_2(S^1)\times\pi_2(S^1) = 0$, so $\operatorname{Hom}(\pi_2(T), \mathbb{R}) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(0, \mathbb{R}) \cong 0$ but $H^2_{\text{dR}}(T) = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @user151938: Yes. The second example I gave can be generalised to show that the isomorphism doesn't hold for any $n > 1$.

Comment: @user151938: For any $n$, you have $H^n(M, \mathbb R) \cong Hom(H_n(M, \mathbb Z), \mathbb R)$, where $H_n(M, \mathbb Z)$ are the singular homology group.

Comment: @John What's the isomorphism between them?

Comment: @user151938: That can be found in this wiki article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem . The Ext group in this case vanish.